# Session storing problems in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I got this issue when trying to store data to $_SESSION variable in Codeigniter 3.03

```
    $search = $_SESSION['search_result']['outbound'];

    $flight = array();
    foreach ($search as $item) {
        if ($item['id'] == $id) {
            $flight = $item;
            break;
        }
    }

    var_dump($flight);

    $_SESSION['selected_outbound'] = $flight;
```

The var_dump function return an unempty array, but when viewing session variable, it empty. Here is my session setting in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASE . '/ci_sessions'; //BASE is root folder
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Instead of using `$_SESSION` directly, I also try to use `$this->session->set_userdata('key', $variable)` but no lucky.

Autoloading session class has been set up.

What am I wrong in this case ? Thanks

Comment: Is your `/ci_sessions` folder writeable?

Comment: Yes, many sessions file created here

Comment: It would be helpful to see how `$_SESSION['search_result']['outbound']` gets set.

Comment: @DFriend: It's an array as I mentioned `var_dump` function return an unempty array.

Comment: So... `var_dump($flight);` outputs a populated array. But after `$_SESSION['selected_outbound'] = $flight;` `var_dump($_SESSION);` outputs nothing?

Comment: `$_SESSION['selected_outbound']` this returns an empty array